# Angularjs directive removes all content from parent div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have custom directive declaration with *replace* set to *true*.

When I place it in html with separate close tag:

```
<div>
    <search-box search="search(query)" query="query" ></search-box>
    <div class="dataDiv">
        <!--other div elements -->
    </div>
</div>
```

everything works as expected.

But after rewriting html in this way:

```
<div>
    <search-box search="search(query)" query="query" />
    <div class="dataDiv">
        <!--other div elements -->
    </div>
</div>
```

directive completely replaces all parent div content with it's template and removes *dataDiv* from resulting html page.

Is this expected angular behavior or something that can be changed in directive declaration?

Directive:

```
function SearchBox() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '...',
        scope: {
            query: '='
        },
        link: function($scope, $element){
            ...
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the doctype?

Comment: That's expected behaviour, **replace: true** replaces the directive contents template or if html from templateUrl..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your doctype you might be giving the wrong meaning to the "closing" slash.
by default, yeoman generator and angular-seed use `<!doctype html>` (html5)

In HTML 5, `<foo />` means `<foo>`. The slash is just [syntactic sugar](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag)
Check this [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

Depending on the browser implementation, it will add automatically a closing tag in one place or another, just like when you leave `body`or `strong` open and read the rendered code.