# angularjs and closing tags

Tags: angularjs, applet

I'm trying to set some params for an applet and the applet does not want to load if there are missing closing tags on the param's.
this is how it should look:

```
<applet>
 <param name='abc' value='def' />
</applet>
```

but as the following plunk will show the output from angular is:

```
<applet>
 <param name='abc' value='def'>
</applet>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/0x7F7AKCkZwEjQR5K4pO
(you have to take a look at the generated code)

I'm not sure why the closing tag matters, but the jar that I'm loading is a 3rd party jar so I can't tell if it has problems with the missing tag, but when I remove angular and just hardcode the params with the closing tag, then my applet loads.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

Comment: I answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23273236/angularjs-directive-removes-all-content-from-parent-div/23273519#23273519

Comment: @Blackhole: not a duplicate.  i don't care if the tag is valid or not...fact is the applet doesn't load without those closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

try to use a individual close tag for param:

```
<applet>
    <param name='abc' value='def'></param>
</applet>
```